# Flask Apache WSGI can not import internal module

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to configure Apache to delploy my Flask app. It works if i run command "python flaskapp.py", but with Apache it can not import internal module Tools

This is my flask app

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import sys
sys.path.append('tools')
import Tools #if i comment this line, not error display and app works ok!

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

This is my .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp python-path=/var/www/html/flaskapp
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi process-group=flaskapp application-group=%{GLOBAL}

    <Directory /var/www/html/flaskapp>
    <Files flaskapp.wsgi>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/html/flaskapp/static
<Directory /var/www/html/flaskapp/static/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

My wsgi file

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/flaskapp')

from flaskapp import app as application
```

My app folders ar /var/www/html/

```
flaskapp/
    -flaskapp.py
    -flaskapp.wsgi
    -static/
    -templates/
    -tools/
        -Tools.py
```

Error log

```
[Thu Mar 09 18:23:23.634661 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3711:tid 140422583609088] [remote 200.69.225.201:9142] mod_wsgi (pid=3711): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Mar 09 18:23:23.634694 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3711:tid 140422583609088] [remote 200.69.225.201:9142] mod_wsgi (pid=3711): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Thu Mar 09 18:23:23.634719 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3711:tid 140422583609088] [remote 200.69.225.201:9142] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Mar 09 18:23:23.634734 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3711:tid 140422583609088] [remote 200.69.225.201:9142]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
[Thu Mar 09 18:23:23.634755 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3711:tid 140422583609088] [remote 200.69.225.201:9142]     from flaskapp import app as application
[Thu Mar 09 18:23:23.634762 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3711:tid 140422583609088] [remote 200.69.225.201:9142]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.py", line 6, in <module>
[Thu Mar 09 18:23:23.634771 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3711:tid 140422583609088] [remote 200.69.225.201:9142]     import Tools
[Thu Mar 09 18:23:23.634783 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3711:tid 140422583609088] [remote 200.69.225.201:9142] ImportError: No module named Tools
```

Comment: You can't use a relative directory when extending ``sys.path``. This is because the current working directory isn't where your code is. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory

Comment: Do you have any ``__init__.py`` files in your directories. Right now it wouldn't be a package and thus why ``from flaskapp.tools import Tools`` wouldn't work, at least for Python 2.7.

Comment: adding __init__.py and complete path to modules works